# Edit Nivo Slider so .live is changed to .on

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I am looking to get the Nivo slider working with the latest version of jQuery. I need to change the .live to .on in order to make it work but a straight swap doesnt work. How do I make it work for jQuery 1.9?

```
if(settings.directionNav){
        slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">'+ settings.prevText +'</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">'+ settings.nextText +'</a></div>');

        $('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            vars.currentSlide -= 2;
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
        });

        $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
        });
    }
```

Comment: You could just download a new copy? I'm not sure when they changed it, but feel free to do a "find" on this: http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider/scripts/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js?ver=3.5.1 -- I can assure you, `.live()` isn't there.

Comment: I went to the site and it said for jquery 1.7 and higher so i assumed it was still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('{element_identifier'}).live(fn)` is equivalent to `$(document).on('evt', '{element_identifier}', fn)`, so here's the swap I'd do:

```
if(settings.directionNav){
        slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">'+ settings.prevText +'</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">'+ settings.nextText +'</a></div>');

        $(document).on('click', 'a.nivo-prevNav, a.nivo-directionNav', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            vars.currentSlide -= 2;
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
        });

        $(document).on('click', 'a.nivo-nextNav', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
        });
    }
```